# Does skill experience get transferred when evolving?

Tags: blood-brothers

When evolving two familiars of the same type, does the skill experience of the seed get transferred to the spawn?

I currently have 2 x Baego, Red Drake familiars with the following stats:

1. Level 70, Skill Level 8
2. Level 1, No skill experience

Obviously I wan't to use the max level one as my seed so I get the 10% stats transfer bonus. But will the skill experience I have earned go across too?

I no I could try this myself, but I am not ready to evolve yet. I want to build up the new one first while I use my veteran version as a back-up and for PvP battles. If the stats do not transfer then I will probably just build the other to Level 70 and use the new "unskilled" one as the seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will only get the 10% stat bonus increase, skill exp will *not* transfer.

Comment: So I should level up the new one to Lv.70 and then use that one as the seed?

Comment: Also, do you know what happens to the spawns XP? If they evolve does it reset the level, or keep the same?

Answer (score 4):

When evolving, the spawn maintains their current Skill XP, and their current level XP.

As an example, say I have a level 70 Cat Sidhe with lvl 20 Rush (his skill).
If I use him as a spawn, regardless of seed stats, I will obtain a level 70 Cat Sidhe II with level 20 Rush.

If I want to get the maximum "bang for my buck", I would use a lvl 70 Cat Sidhe for the seed also, to obtain the 10% stat bonus.

This would result in the following Evolution.
Cat Sidhe (lvl 70) *Skill - Rush (lvl 20)* [**Spawn**]
+ Cat Sidhe (lvl 70) *Skill - Rush (lvl 1)* [**Seed**]
= Cat Sidhe II (lvl 70) *Skill - Rush (lvl 20)*

This is from experience, as I have done this exact Evolution!